# How can I parse a char array with octal values in Python?

Tags: python-2.7, arrays, octal

EDIT: I should note that I want a general case for any hex array, not just the google one I provided.

EDIT BACKGROUND: Background is networking: I'm parsing a DNS packet and trying to get its QNAME. I'm taking in the whole packet as a string, and every character represents a byte. Apparently this problem looks like a Pascal string problem, and using the struct module seems like the way to go.

I have a char array in Python 2.7 which includes octal values. For example, let's say I have an array

```
DNS = "\03www\06google\03com\0"
```

I want to get:

> [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)

What's an efficient way to do this? My first thought would be iterating through the DNS char array and adding chars to my new array answer. Every time i see a '\' char, I would ignore the '\' and two chars after it. Is there a way to get the resulting www.google.com without using a new array?

my disgusting implementation (my answer is an array of chars, which is not what i want, i want just the string www.google.com:

```
DNS = "\\03www\\06google\\03com\\0"
answer = []
i = 0
while i < len(DNS):
    if DNS[i] == '\\' and DNS[i+1] != 0:
        i += 3    
    elif DNS[i] == '\\' and DNS[i+1] == 0:
        break
    else:
        answer.append(DNS[i])
        i += 1
```

Comment: strip all matches of '\\[1-0,a-f][1-0,a-f]' with regex

Comment: Where did you get this from? If you had a string with actual control characters in its (actually, they look like length prefixes), like `'\03www\06google\03com\0'` and escaped those in some earlier step, I would suggest not doing that earlier step.

Comment: are you sure that's hex?  `DNS` should look like `'\x03www\x06google\x03com\x00'` if so..

Comment: I suppose they are just hex representations, since they are in a string

Comment: Are you sure they're not octal representations? Because `\03` and `\06` and `\0` are all valid C-style octal character escapes, as might be used by some escaping function someone wrote in C.

Comment: @abarnert, I believe you are correct, I will edit

Comment: Why does the string look like this? What meaning are these escapes supposed to have? Why are there different ones for two different periods?

Comment: Also, `DNS = "\03www\06google\03com\0"` doesn't produce a string with backslashes and digits in it; it produces a string with unprintable characters in it.

Comment: @user2357112: That's right, when you try to print DNS, it prints the letters with some weird number representation I'm not sure of. The backslash numbers represent how many letters follow, for example, \03 means 3 letters will follow before another /xx value

Comment: @user2649452: OK, now you're contradicting yourself. Is your string `"\03www\06google\03com\0"`, which prints out with invisible characters in it, or is it `"\\03www\\06google\\03com\\0"`, which prints out with backslashes and numbers? Because an answer that works for one will not work for the other, obviously.

Comment: More importantly, please, where did you get this from? If you know who escaped/encoded it and how and why, it's a lot easier to figure out how to reverse that correctly than trying to guess from one very small example.

Comment: @user2649452: The string is "\03www\06google\03com\0", which prints out weird characters.

Comment: @abarnert: Background is networking: I'm parsing a DNS packet and trying to get its QNAME. I'm taking in the whole packet as a string, and every character represents a byte. I think your answer regarding Pascal strings is the right intuition, maybe using the struct module there is a very easy way to do this?

Comment: @user2649452: Yes, if you want to parse DNS packets, you should parse [the DNS protocol](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1035.txt), not grab bits out of it and try to guess how to morph them into useful strings. (For the future, please read [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), which will hopefully help you avoid writing questions that get half a dozen incorrect answers before people figure out what you want.)

Comment: @abarnert: Thanks for the reference, I assumed this could be an isolated string problem and I assumed wrong. I supposed I should discontinue this post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that you've explained your real problem, none of the answers you've gotten so far will work. Why? Because they're all ways to remove sequences like `\03` from a string. But you don't *have* sequences like `\03`, you have single control characters.

You could, of course, do something similar, just replacing any control character with a dot.

But what you're *really* trying to do is not replace control characters with dots, but parse DNS packets.

DNS is defined by [RFC 1035](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1035.txt). The QNAME in a DNS packet is:

> a domain name represented as a sequence of labels, where each label consists of a length octet followed by that number of octets.  The domain name terminates with the zero length octet for the null label of the root.  Note that this field may be an odd number of octets; no padding is used.

So, let's parse that. If you understand how "labels consisting of "a length octet followed by that number of octets" relates to "Pascal strings", there's a quicker way. Also, you could write this more cleanly and less verbosely as a generator. But let's do it the dead-simple way:

```
def parse_qname(packet):
    components = []
    offset = 0
    while True:
        length, = struct.unpack_from('B', packet, offset)
        offset += 1
        if not length:
            break
        component = struct.unpack_from('{}s'.format(length), packet, offset)
        offset += length
        components.append(component)
    return components, offset
```

Comment: I need to take a LONG look at this as I am very confused. I don't even understand why DNS = "\03www\06google\03com\0" would print invisible characters, isn't this just a string?

Comment: @user2649452 if you input that string directly to python, it interprets those escaped characters as *hex*.  `\x03` is ONE character - the end-of-text control character, aka ctrl-c.  If this doesn't make sense, try doing `len('\03')`

Comment: @user2649452: The official tutorial section on [Strings](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) explains a little about how backslash escapes work, although I suspect it only helps if you already know the difference between string literals and string objects, and have a vague understanding of C… There's probably a better tutorial on this somewhere…

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
DNS = "\\03www\\06google\\03com\\0"
m = re.sub("\\\\([0-9,a-f]){2}", "", DNS)
print(m)
```

Comment: Hmm, so I get wwwgooglecom\0 with this method. Is there any way to take out the \0 and add periods in this implementation?

Comment: @user2649452: If you read the documentation for [`re.sub`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub), and look at what Raiyan is passing for the second parameter (the `repl`), the answer to that should be obvious.

Comment: @Raiyan: It would be a lot nicer to write this regexp as a raw string instead of escaping the backslashes.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import re

def convert(adorned_hostname):
    result1 = re.sub(r'^\\03', '', adorned_hostname )
    result2 = re.sub(r'\\0[36]', '.', result1)
    result3 = re.sub(r'\\0$', '', result2)
    return result3

def main():
    adorned_hostname = r"\03www\06google\03com\0"
    expected_result = 'www.google.com'
    actual_result = convert(adorned_hostname)
    print(actual_result, expected_result)
    assert actual_result == expected_result

main()
```

Comment: I'm actually looking for a method that can take in any array with hex values like the one I gave and output the right string. Is there anyway you make this apply generally? (EDIT added to post)

Answer (score 1):

For the question as originally asked, replacing the backslash-hex sequences in strings like `"\\03www\\06google\\03com\\0"` with dots…

If you want to do this with a regular expression:

- `\\` matches a backslash.
- `[0-9A-Fa-f]` matches any hex digit.
- `[0-9A-Fa-f]+` matches one or more hex digits.
- `\\[0-9A-Fa-f]+` matches a backslash followed by one or more hex digits.

You want to find each such sequence, and replace it with a dot, right? If you look through the `re` docs, you'll find a function called [`sub`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) which is used for replacing a pattern with a replacement string:

```
re.sub(r'\\[0-9A-Fa-f]+', '.', DNS)
```

I suspect these may actually be octal, not hex, in which case you want `[0-7]` rather than `[0-9A-Fa-f]`, but nothing else would change.

---

A different way to do this is to recognize that these are valid Python escape sequences. And, if we unescape them back to where they came from (e.g., with `DNS.decode('string_escape')`), this turns into a sequence of length-prefixed (aka "Pascal") strings, a standard format that you can parse in any number of ways, including the stdlib `struct` module. This has the advantage of validating the data as you read it, and not being thrown off by any false positives that could show up if one of the string components, say, had a backslash in the middle of it.

Of course that's presuming more about the data. It seems *likely* that the real meaning of this is "a sequence of length-prefixed strings, concatenated, then backslash-escaped", in which case you should parse it as such. But it *could* be just a coincidence that it looks like that, in which case it would be a very bad idea to parse it as such.